# Proving you are the best StackExchange-User

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, obfuscation

### Write one/two program(s)/function(s):

1. The first one should return a truthy value if given your Stack Exchange username.

#### ~~Optional~~

2. An obfuscated one (as explained below) that does the same thing.

#### Rules for number 2:

1. May be no more than ten times the byte-count of number 1 or 100 bytes, whichever is higher.
2. Must be written in the same language as number 1.

## Test cases

(for my case:)

```
input        output
-------------------
Seims        true
BestCoderXX  false
```

#### Winning

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest byte count for number one wins.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You've chosen a [minefield](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8242/42963) as your [first challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8134/42963) question, so fair warning for that. Additionally, I've voted to close your challenge as Too Broad, since "Make your code as obfuscated as possible" is exceedingly broad. That said, I hope you enjoy your time here and again, welcome!

Comment: @Seims I hope you see the value of the Sandbox. :D

Comment: "Your username may not occur in the code in any of these forms", that's not very clear, if the arguments of the function spell my name, but they don't change the outcome of the function, does that count?

Comment: And please, refrain from changing the challenge halfway trough

Comment: the title is irrelevant

Comment: also i have a [sandboxed challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9157/38337) about obfuscating the way you want a "fix" name printed, with measures the thing your challenge is lacking, you must specify measures which by an obfuscation-technique is better than the other.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+([]+(+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([]+(+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]])()(+[]+[+[]]+(+[![]])+![])[+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]])()+[])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[!![]+!![]+!![]]]+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))[(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]])()([][[]]))[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]](![])+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]])())()
```

To run:
Open the console (`Ctrl + Shift + I`)
Type `f =`
Paste the above

To use:
`f('the string you want to test')`

### EDIT: fixed ES6 version below

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+([]+(+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([]+(+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]])()(+[]+[+[]]+(+[![]])+![])[+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]])()+[])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[!![]+!![]+!![]]]+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![]))[(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]])()([][[]]))[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]](![])+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]])())()
```

Note: This checks equality with the username of whoever runs it, not my username

Comment: What obfuscator do you use? This looks like Brainfuck

Comment: @Bálint [JSFuck.](http://www.jsfuck.com/)

Comment: This doesn't work. What is your name? Not `somebody`.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ `Note: This checks equality with the username of whoever runs it, not my username`

Comment: Doesn't work for my name.

Comment: Ah, didn't work for me either when I tried "fede s." "fede s" "fedes" etc... It worked with "fede-s", so I'm guessing it might be the whitespace @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ ?

Comment: Then it needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2 (Non-Competing)

*This was posted before the rules were changed significantly.*

```
False = True; True = False; True = True; print (`'Riker'.lower().upper()`=="Riker" and "Riker" == `raw_input()`) <> True and raw_input()=="Riker"
```

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript

```
eval(function(B,á,l,i,n,t){if(n=function(B){return B},!"".replace(/^/,String)){for(;l--;)t[l]=i[l]||l;i=[function(B){return t[B]}],n=function(){return"\\w+"},l=1}for(;l--;)i[l]&&(B=B.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+n(l)+"\\b","g"),i[l]));return B}('3 4(0){2(!(0=="9á5")){{1 7}}6{{1 8}}}',10,10,"notMyName|return|if|function|HELLO_WORLD|lint|else|false|true|B".split("|"),0,{}));
```

I first created a half-readable code, then I ran it trough RegPack, then an obfuscator, then a minifier, then RegPack again, and lastly a different minifier.

Note: RegPack is worse than an obfuscator

Made a slight modification on variable names after @LeakyNun pointed out something

Comment: You should make the six variables spell your name :)

Comment: @LeakyNun That's actually a cool idea

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2 (Non-Competing)

*This was posted before the rules were changed significantly.*

```
print raw_input()=="Eᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏ Iʀᴋ"
```

Quite obfuscated to non-programmers or people who only code in brainfuck.

@Downvoters: Also serves to point out the definition of "obfuscated" needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth)

```
q1409257787840474805614C
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=q1409257787840474805614C&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22Leaky+Nun%22%0A%22Nyan+Luke%22&debug=0)

Encodes the input string in base-256, and then check if it is equal to `1409257787840474805614`.

Comment: But this is simple string encoding....

Comment: @BaldBantha could you tell that spells “leaky nun”?

Answer (score 4):

### 05AB1E

```
žnžo‡"Vnrtmz"Q
```

Uses the Atbash cipher.

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xb5uxb5v4oChIlZucnRteiJR&input=RW1pZ25h)

Answer (score 4):

## Java

```
public boolean eval( String username )
{
    int s = 2304854;
    int w = 1660790;
    String r = "";
    int l = username.length();
    int b = 0;
    Random ra = new Random( s );
    boolean sw = false;
    for ( int i = 0; i < l; i++ )
    {
        if ( !sw && i > 5 )
        {
            sw = true;
            ra = new Random( w );
        }
        int ran = ra.nextInt( 25 ) + 97;
        b |= ( ( i == 5 ? ' ' : ran - ( ( i == 0 || i == 6 ) ? 32 : 0 ) == username.getBytes()[ i ] ? 1 : 0 ) << i );
    }
    return b == 2015 && l == 10;
}
```

## None- Golfed

```
public boolean isShaunWild(String name){
    return name.equals("Shaun Wild");
}
```

Just a bit of fun haha. Horribly unreadable and hard to understand what it is without reading through it a couple of million times :<sup>)</sup>

Comment: +1) I was thinking about similar solution, but first i split it into couple functions, and seed wasn't plain number, but it was result of some obscure calculations

Comment: I was actually going to do that but I didn't want to put it across more than one function and I ran out of time at my office and had to leave so I couldn't obfuscate the seeds further.

Answer (score 3):

## Oracle SQL 11.2

Returns 0 if true, 1 if false

```sql
SELECT SIGN(ABS(TRUNC(SUM(ASCII(SUBSTR(:1,LEVEL,1))*POWER(10,LEVEL*(LENGTH(:1)-1.14265533)))/CEIL(AVG(LEVEL))-
       CEIL(AVG(POWER(ASCII(SUBSTR(:1,LEVEL,1)),6.42)))+76158.880743588573892)))
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=LENGTH(:1)
```

Answer (score 3):

### Perl 5

```
eval eval '"'.('`'|'%').('['^'-').('`'|'!').('`'|',').('{'^'[').('['^'.').('`'|'.').('['^'+').('`'|'!').('`'|'#').('`'|'+').('{'^'[').('['^'.').'='.'>'.('['^'*').'\\'.'{'.'_'.(';'&'=').('^'^('`'|')')).(';'&'=').('`'^'!').';'.'\\'.'"'.'!'.('{'^'.').';'.('`'^"'").'!'.('`'^'!').(':'&'=').('{'^'-').('`'^',').('`'^'"').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^',').'-'.('^'^('`'|',')).'('.('`'^',').'('.('`'^'%').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.('^'^('`'|'*')).(';'&'=').'<'.'>'.'#'.'('.('{'^'"').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^')').'-'.('^'^('`'|'+')).('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.('^'^('`'|'*')).'-'.'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'+')).'\\'.'$'.('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^')').('^'^('`'|'.')).('^'^('`'|'+')).('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('`'^'#').'-'.'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'*')).('{'^'+').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'.').('^'^('`'|'/')).('^'^('`'|'+')).('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('{'^'(').('`'^'%').'<'.'>'.'#'.','.('{'^',').'_'.('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^')').'-'.'%'.('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.'#'.')'.'<'.'>'.'#'.','.('{'^',').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^')').'-'.('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.'#'.'!'.'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'*')).('{'^'.').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^')').('^'^('`'|'.')).('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('`'^'#').('^'^('`'|'+')).'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'*')).('{'^'*').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'.').'.'.'%'.('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('`'^'$').('^'^('`'|'/')).'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'.')).('{'^'(').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^')').'-'.('^'^('`'|'+')).('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('{'^'/').'-'.'<'.'>'.'#'.'-'.'%'.('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^')').'_'.','.('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('{'^'/').'-'.'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'*')).('{'^'.').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'(').'-'.('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('`'^'#').'='.'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'.')).('{'^'+').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'.').'-'.('`'^'%').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('{'^'(').('`'^'!').'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'*')).('{'^'.').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'.').','.('^'^('`'|'+')).('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.('^'^('`'|'-')).('`'^'!').'<'.'>'.'#'.')'.'#'.('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'/').','.('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('`'^'#').'%'.'<'.'>'.'#'.'-'.'#'.('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'(').('^'^('`'|'/')).('^'^('`'|'+')).('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'_'.','.('`'^'#').'-'.'<'.'>'.'#'.','.('{'^'/').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'.').','.'%'.('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('{'^'(').'='.'<'.'>'.'#'.'('.('{'^',').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'/').','.'%'.('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.('^'^('`'|'-')).(';'&'=').'<'.'>'.'#'.')'.'%'.('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'(').'-'.('^'^('`'|'+')).('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.('^'^('`'|'-')).'%'.'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'*')).('{'^'#').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^')').('^'^('`'|'/')).'%'.('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.'#'.'-'.'<'.'>'.'#'.')'.'\\'.'$'.('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'(').('^'^('`'|'.')).('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('{'^'/').('^'^('`'|'+')).'<'.'_'.'>'.'#'.'('.('{'^'(').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'(').'.'.'%'.('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.('^'^('`'|'-')).'%'.'<'.'>'.'#'.','.('{'^',').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^')').'-'.('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.'#'.'!'.'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'*')).('{'^',').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^')').('^'^('`'|'.')).('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'+')).'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'*')).('{'^'*').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'.').'.'.'%'.('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('`'^'$').('^'^('`'|'/')).'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'.')).('{'^'(').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'(').','.'%'.('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.'#'.')'.'<'.'>'.'#'.')'.'!'.'_'.('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'(').','.('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.('^'^('`'|'*')).'-'.'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'.')).('{'^')').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'(').'-'.('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('`'^'#').'='.'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'.')).('{'^'+').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'.').'-'.('^'^('`'|'+')).('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('`'^'$').('^'^('`'|'/')).'<'.'>'.'#'.'('.('{'^'.').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'.').','.('^'^('`'|'+')).('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.('^'^('`'|'-')).('`'^'!').'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'.')).('{'^'#').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^')').('^'^('`'|'/')).'%'.('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.('^'^('`'|'-')).'-'.'<'.'>'.'#'.'('.('{'^'"').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'(').'_'.('^'^('`'|'.')).('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('{'^'/').('^'^('`'|'+')).'<'.'>'.'#'.'('.('{'^'(').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'(').('^'^('`'|'.')).('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.('^'^('`'|'-')).('^'^('`'|'+')).'<'.'>'.'#'.','.('{'^',').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^')').'-'.('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.'#'.'!'.'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'*')).('{'^'-').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^')').('^'^('`'|'/')).'%'.('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('{'^'(').')'.'<'.'>'.'#'.'('.('{'^'#').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'.').('^'^('`'|'.')).('^'^('`'|'+')).('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('`'^'#').('`'^'!').'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'.')).('{'^'.').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'.').','.('^'^('`'|'+')).('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'_'.'-'.('^'^('`'|'-')).('`'^'!').'<'.'>'.'#'.')'.'\\'.'$'.('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^')').','.('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('{'^'(').('`'^'%').'<'.'>'.'#'.'-'.'#'.('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'(').('^'^('`'|'/')).('^'^('`'|'+')).('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('`'^'#').'-'.'<'.'>'.'#'.','.('{'^'#').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'.').','.('^'^('`'|'+')).('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('{'^'(').'='.'<'.'>'.'#'.'('.('{'^',').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'/').','.'%'.('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.('^'^('`'|'-')).(';'&'=').'<'.'>'.'#'.','.('{'^'#').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'.').'-'.('^'^('`'|'+')).('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.('^'^('`'|'-')).'%'.'<'.'_'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'*')).('{'^'#').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^')').('^'^('`'|'/')).'%'.('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.('^'^('`'|'-')).'-'.'<'.'>'.'#'.')'.'\\'.'$'.('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'(').('^'^('`'|'.')).('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('{'^'/').('^'^('`'|'+')).'<'.'>'.'#'.'('.('{'^'(').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'(').'.'.'%'.('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.('^'^('`'|'-')).('^'^('`'|'+')).'<'.'>'.'#'.'('.('{'^'#').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'/').','.('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.'\\'.'$'.('^'^('`'|'/')).'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'*')).('{'^'+').('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'(').('^'^('`'|'.')).('{'^'.').('{'^'*').('{'^'#').'-'.'#'.(';'&'=').'<'.'>'.'#'.('^'^('`'|'.')).('{'^'.').')'.('^'^('`'|')'))."'".'\\'.'@'.('{'^'/').('^'^('`'|'/')).('^'^('`'|'+')).('{'^'*').('{'^'#').','.('{'^'/').('^'^('`'|'.')).('`'^'"').'\\'.'}'.('!'^'+').'"'
```

Original code was a one liner, now... it's technically still a one liner.

[Try it here!](https://ideone.com/qrbWzO)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6)

```
(s)=>/(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)\3[^\1]{6}\2[^\2]{5}\5[^\3]{6}\4[^\4]{5}\6[^\5]{7}\7[^\6]{10}\1[^\7]+/.test(s+atob("YWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXogQUJDREVGR0hJSktMTU5PUFFSU1RVVldYWVo="))
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6

My answer assumes an only-ASCII encoding. This, I am sure, is the optimal solution for JavaScript ES6 in such a setting--this is the only encoding I wish to cover. If anyone wishes to tackle non-ASCII JS, be my guest ;) This clocks in at 61 bytes, leaving me 610 bytes to obfuscate.

```
n=>n=="C\u1d0f\u0274\u1d0f\u0280 O'B\u0280\u026a\u1d07\u0274"
```

Here is my obfuscated version, clocking in 588 bytes, less than 610.

```
(c,f,d,W=this,k=e=>+(`0x`+e),C=(O,...m)=>new(O[w=`constructor`]!=C[w]?O[w]:O)(...m))=>(($,_)=>$<=_&&_<=$)([g=W[(-~(Math.sqrt((P=parseInt)(P,b=31))+P(NaN,b+=5))+0xec)[D=`toString`](b)],t=n=>(j=n=>W[n[D](b)])(n),E=W[505019[D](b)]([...[1663483,552948,1629769,516801].map(e=>e[D](b)).join``].map((s,i)=>+(42742[D](2)[i])?s.toUpperCase():s).join``),A=n=>(p,c)=>p+n+c,...[for(x of c)x.charCodeAt()]].slice(-c.length),g(`[${[...`1${[...`mn0nkjp0mio0nkjp0mkg0ji0np0jp0mm0mkg0mho0nkjh0mio`].reduce(A(-~[]))}`.match(/../g).map(e=>""[w][E](P(e,b)-4)).reduce(a)].reduce((p,c)=>c<"!"?`${p},`:p+c)}]`))
```

### Bonus material

This was my original, 947-byte obfuscation for the original challenge:

```
(c,d,f,M=Math,W=Z=this,q=($,_)=>$<=_&&_<=$,k=e=>+[`${+[+[]][+[]]}x`+e][+[]],
C=(O,...m)=>new(O[w=`constructor`]!=C[w]?O[w]:O)(...m))=>q([[d=[f=[~c]]+f],g
=W[(-~(M.sqrt(parseInt(P=parseInt,b=~-[[_=+!+[]<<-~![]][+[]]<<[_<<_/_][+[]]]
))+P(NaN,b+=5))+(e=>+[`${+[+[]][+[]]}x`+e][+[]])(C([],...C(Set,[..."abced"].
map(j=>j+i+(u+=[[u,u]],(i=j>i?j:i)?i:[]),i=u=[])[M.atan2(u[l="length"],~[]<<
~[])>>[]])).reduce(a=(p,c)=>p+c,[]+[]))|+[])[D=`toString`](b)],t=n=>(j=n=>W[
n[D](b)])(n),E=t(h=505019)([...[1663483,552948,1629769,h+=11782].map(e=>e[D]
(b)).reduce(a)].map((s,i)=>+[42742[D](2)][+[]][i]?s.toUpperCase():s).reduce(
a)),A=n=>(p,c)=>p+n+c,...[for(x of c)x[`c${E.slice(-7)}${[[]+[]][+[]][w][E](
P(42/_,_<<_<<_))+`${[]+[]}t`}`]()]].slice(-c[l]),g(`[${[...`1${[...`mn0nkjp`
+`0mio0nkjp0mkg0ji0np0jp0mm0mkg0mho0nkjh0mio`].reduce(A(-~[]))}`.match(/../g
).map(e=>[[]+[]][+[]][w][E](P(e,b)-4)).reduce(a)].reduce((p,c)=>c<"!"?`${p},
`:p+c)}]`))
```

Comment: +1 for making the evil more evil

Comment: @Seims Well, actually, I made the evil less evil in order for it to fit under 610 bytes ^_^

Answer (score 0):

## C++11

Golfed (129 characters including whitespaces):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int main(){std::string s;std::cin>>s;std::cout<<(s.compare("dorukayhan")==0?"true":"false");}
```

Obfuscated (much less than 1290 characters):

```
                                                             #define import using namespace
                                                                         #include<iostream>
                                                                           #include<string>
                                                                            #define def int
import std                                                                                ;

def main()                                                                                {
    string s                                                                              ;
    cin >> s                                                                              ;
    char c[] = {100, 111, 114, 117, 107, 97, 121, 104, 97, 110, 0}                        ;
    cout << (s.compare(c) == 0 ? "true" : "false")                                       ;}
```